# Print Ribbon using PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

that drives me nuts. I try to silent print a ribbon (1000 mm height, 150 mm width). The content is a Canvas containing a formatted Text.

If I use "Microsoft Print To PDF" it works and looks OK. When i go on and use the OKI Printer from the pdf it is fine!

If I directly try to print using the OKI, I will get a blank ribbon or (if i change some parameters) I get a very small text in the middle of nowhere.

Any ideas? Unfortunatly it is nearly impossible to Debug.

This is the print function:

```
        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();
        //PrintQueue queue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print To PDF");
        PrintQueue queue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("OKI C3450");

        prnt.PrintQueue = queue;
        //var f = queue.GetPrintCapabilities();
        prnt.PrintTicket = new PrintTicket();
        prnt.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(3779.53, 566.93);
        prnt.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        //if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
        //{
            Size pageSize = new Size(3779.53, 566.93);

        var canvasToPrint = this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1;

        this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1.Measure(pageSize);
        this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1.Children.RemoveRange(0, this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1.Children.Count-1);
        this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));

        //if (prnt.ShowDialog() == true)
        //{
       // try
        //{
            prnt.PrintVisual(this.backgroundCanvasSchleife1, "Printing Canvas");
        //}catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    var t = ex;
        //}
            //}
        //}
        //this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: a solution could be to embed the result in a pdf viewer and from there to print. Wouldn't that fix it? I had a similar issue using a different language. My problem was with a thermal printer and doing that fixed it for me. The "real" problem could be that the printer is non standard and therefore refer to non standard sizing that your program cannot understand.

Comment: sounds like a plan. I will try that, thanks